Difference between [0]*n with [0 for _ in range(n)]
I'm trying to solve leetcode problem, for the same function, when I initialize the array with self.preSum = [[0] * (n_col+1) for _ in range(n_row+1)], the result is correct and when I initializ the array with self.presum = [[0] * (n_col+1)] * (n_row+1), the result is wrong (array not keep value in for loop)
Can somebody please explain why this happened and what's the best practice to create empty array in python?
class NumMatrix:

    def __init__(self, matrix: List[List[int]]):
        n_row = len(matrix)
        n_col = len(matrix[0])

        # This NOT work
        # self.presum = [[0] * (n_col+1)] * (n_row+1)
        # print(self.presum)

        # This works! Why???
        self.preSum = [[0] * (n_col+1) for _ in range(n_row+1)]
        print(self.preSum)


        for i in range(0, n_row):
            for j in range(0, n_col):
                self.presum[i+1][j+1] = (self.presum[i][j+1] + self.presum[i+1][j] + matrix[i][j] - self.presum[i][j])
                
    def sumRegion(self, row1: int, col1: int, row2: int, col2: int) -> int:

        return self.presum[row2+1][col2+1] - self.presum[row1][col2+1] - self.presum[row2+1][col1] + self.presum[row1][col1]
        


# Your NumMatrix object will be instantiated and called as such:
# obj = NumMatrix(matrix)
# param_1 = obj.sumRegion(row1,col1,row2,col2)

    # This NOT work
    # self.presum = [[0] * (n_col+1)] * (n_row+1)
    # print(self.presum)

    # This works! Why???
    self.preSum = [[0] * (n_col+1) for _ in range(n_row+1)]
    print(self.preSum)


What you put in the title does not reflect what you actually do in your code, nor does it have that problem.
